Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(x-3)\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Determine if improper integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(x-3)\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
is convergent.


Function $f(x) = \frac{(x-3)\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}$ is defined $\forall x \in \Bbb R$ so I should take care of what happens for $x\to \pm \infty$. I notice that
$$f(x) = \underbrace{\frac{x\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}}_A- \underbrace{\frac{3\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}}_B$$
where $(B)$ for $x\to \pm\infty$ has the same order of $1/x^2$ hence the integral is convergent.
$(A)$ is more delicate but also for $x\to \pm \infty$
$$A \sim \frac{\cos(2x)}{x}$$
I use integration by parts to get
$$\int \frac{\cos(2x)}{x} dx = \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}+\color{red}{\int \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x^2}dx} $$
where red part highlighted is a convergent integral for the same argument used for $(B)$, hence also $(A)$ is convergent.

Is my approach formally correct? I noticed lately that I've poor capacity on formalize these type of reasoning since I'm not very sure when to use for example $|f(x)|$ for
estimates or asymptotic...
Thank you very much any help appreciated!

I'd use integration by parts to prove the convergence for $(A)$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x\cos(2x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac12\sin(2x)\frac x{1+x^2}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(2x)\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\mathrm dx $$
and it's easy to show the convergence of the last integral analyzing the dominant terms and bounding $\sin (2x)$ with $1$. Note that the asymptotic test works for positive functions.

So my reasoning is a bit flawed since $A$ hasn't constant sign in a neighborhood of $\infty$ and I should take the absolute values, see that the estimate you propose with integration by part, bound $A$. It says in my book that asymptotic test is only for constant sign functions, but unfortunately I still don't fully get that part...

@TurquoiseTilt Your reasoning is not correct since you need to consider functions with the same sign. If $f\sim g$ then you can't conclude $\int f$ and $\int g$ both converge/diverge, unless $f$ and $g$ has the same sign

Would you be kind enough to summarize what happen when we do not have constant sign and still use asymptotic? Or a counterexample, because I think it's crucial to understand this in order to have good work flow on this type of questions

@TurquoiseTilt Sure, see this post for example. Let me know if it's clear
